# Server cannot set status after HTTP headers have been sent with MVC custom Authorize Attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-authorization

I am using ASP.NET MVC5 with my custom AuthorizeAttribute as below

```
protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var httpContext = filterContext.HttpContext;
        var request = httpContext.Request;
        var response = httpContext.Response;
        var user = httpContext.User;

        if (request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated == false)
            {
                response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
                response.StatusDescription = "You must be Login to process this request!";
            }
            else
            {
                response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
                response.StatusDescription = "Permission Denied! Please contact your Administrator";
            }

            response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true;
            response.End();
        }

        base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
    }
```

When i am trying to send a responce code of 403 from above code i always got an exception from Application_Error method of Global.asax.cs having

> System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Server cannot set status after HTTP headers have been sent.

Below is the Stack trace

> System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Server cannot set status after HTTP headers have been sent.
>      at System.Web.HttpResponse.set_StatusCode(Int32 value)
>      at System.Web.HttpResponseWrapper.set_StatusCode(Int32 value)
>      at DevOdeeERP.Web.Support.SharedMVC.DodBaseController.OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.IExceptionFilter.OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeExceptionFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, Exception exception)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
>      at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
>      at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>      at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Comment: The stacktrace actually only shows one bit of your code, and that is a controller's OnException method. Have you tried setting a breakpoint in your authorization attribute and seeing where exactly it throws the exception? Also, I'm not sure you need to call `base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext)` since you already set the response to what you want.

Comment: The breakpoint goes pretty neatly with authorization attribute , no exception. Then suddenly it calls controllers OnException Method with the above error. If i do not call `base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext)` it allows the code to execute even when it is not authenticated.

Comment: Try moving `response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true` before checking `user.Identity.IsAuthenticated` state. Your `HandleUnauthorizedRequest` method tries to write 403 HTTP status code after the header has been created and sent to the client (probably set as HTTP 200). Remember that once the header has been sent, you can no longer put any status code.